# Using date, time and code values to extract and feature engineer data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:-

```
ID  Amt Bal Code    Date    Time
xy1 12  900 38  01/10/2019  12:11
xy1 10  900 38  01/10/2019  12:56
xy1 35  900 14  01/10/2019  13:55
xy1 300 900 39  01/10/2019  23:59
xy1 600 900 39  01/10/2019  23:18
xy1 60  900 39  01/10/2019  0:18
xy1 55  900 14  01/10/2019  1:18
xy1 95  900 38  04/10/2019  2:18
xy1 85  900 38  05/10/2019  3:18
xy1 32  900 39  05/10/2019  4:18
```

I need to add up the count of all the instances where the code is 38 or 39 before code turns 14/22 for every ID.
I have done it by separating the dataframes but I was wondering is there was an easier way to do it using the time instance

So if xy1 ID has code 38 twice before first instance of code 14 and then there is code 38/39 thrice before code 14 comes again the df should be like:-

```
id  Amount                 Bal  Before 1st 14   After 1st Before 2nd 14
xy1 (sumofamountincode14)   900     2                3
```

Something on these lines, I have been trying from yesterday and requirement doesn't make much sense I know.

Comment: Your best bet would be to create the subset of data based on your condition and then count all the instances of code 38/39

Comment: That would be too many subsets. I have multiple codes, I was hoping to edit whatever solution I get accordingly.